# How did Voldemort know he could access Harry's mind but not realise this was because part of his soul was latched onto him?

Tags: harry-potter

Once Voldemort realised he could access Harry's mind in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, how did he not realise this was because part of his soul was latched onto him?

Comment: First version was good. Why did you edit the title? Keep the title simple.

Comment: Apologies, but I had to edit it because Harry is not a Horcrux. See here - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11530/how-did-harry-become-a-horcrux/11546#11546

Comment: Harry not a horcrux? That would make whole Harry potter series no sense. He was not intentionally horcrux. But he is a Horcrux.

Comment: @SS. Did you even read the link?  JKR herself said that a Horcrux is deliberate, and that what happened with Harry wasn't technically a Horcrux because of the accidental nature.

Comment: @JMac Yeah. I did. But that is not easy to digest. Voldemort didn't cast the horcrux spell in case of harry. It was accidental. I know that. But a part of Voldemort's soul lived in Harry . Isn't it?

Comment: @SS. "the definition will be that a receptacle is prepared by Dark Magic to become the receptacle of a fragmented piece of soul, and that that piece of soul was deliberately detached from the master soul to act as a future safeguard, or anchor, to life, and a safeguard against death."  This was accidental, and therefore not a Horcrux, even if it performed the same actions.

Comment: Same question on S&F SE by the same user: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157037/how-did-voldemort-know-he-could-access-harrys-mind-but-not-realise-this-was-be

Answer (score 2):

Because he was under impression that he is using magic for same. He was using [Legilimency Spell](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Legilimency_Spell) for same, the part of his soul made the connection strong , however Voldemort would have been able to access Harry's mind anyways.

> The Legilimency Spell (Legilimens) allows the caster to perform Legilimency; in other words, to delve into the mind of the victim, permitting the caster to see memories, emotions and thoughts. Skilled Legilimens, such as Lord Voldemort, are able to perform Legilimency without using the incantation or a wand.
>
> Voldemort has used this spell extensively, both wandlessly and nonverbally, to enter the minds of those he wished to interrogate. Due to the link between himself and Harry, both can access each other's thoughts if Voldemort does not block it off with Occlumency.

Voldemort  might had believed that Harry is weak and hence his mind is easily accessible.

Most of people believed this connection is due to the scar gave by Voldemort. He himself believed same, he never thought about soul being latched as this was rare case.

Answer (score 2):

*Because:*

- *No one knew this was possible – except for Professor Dumbledore himself.*
- *Voldemort’s huge ego prevented him from analyzing it further.*

No one knew this was possible.

Up until it happened, everyone thought the Killing Curse could not be stopped or blocked. “Professor Moody” (Barty Crouch Jr) said so when he was teaching Defense Against the Dark Arts. He stated that the only one known to have survived this curse is Harry. And the reason for this was a mystery to all but a very few. Harry was simply “the boy who lived”.

Only Dumbledore (and later Voldemort) figured out that the Killing Curse could be made to rebound off of someone who is protected by the *ancient magic of love*. Lily Potter died to protect the son whom she loved. Only Dumbledore reasoned out the following:

- Because of Lily, Harry was protected.
- The Killing Curse rebounded and hit Voldemort, destroying his body but not his soul because of the horcruxes Voldemort created beforehand.
- Harry could speak to snakes.
- Only the rare descendants of Slytherin spoke to snakes.
- Harry was either a descendant *or something else*.
- An additional part of Voldemort’s soul was ripped from what remained in his body and latched onto the only living thing in the vicinity: Harry.
- That's why Harry can speak to snakes.

Again, only Dumbledore riddled this out (I guess the pun was intended). *No one else knew this*. Recall when Dumbledore was giving instructions to Professor Snape on what to do after Dumbledore died. He had to specifically say that only Voldemort is the one who had to “kill” Harry. He had to give these *exact* instructions because no one knew (including all the Death Eaters) that Harry had to have Voldemort’s soul fragment removed before Harry could be cured. So Harry had to be "killed" by the only person where the Killing Curse would not work -- Voldemort. And Voldemort's ego pretty much guaranteed that he would be the one to "kill" Harry.

Voldemort’s huge ego prevented him from analyzing it further.

Voldemort never took the time to be this analytical – because of his enormous ego. He was very intelligent, but not interested in being an academic. He just wanted to be the *most at everything he considered important*: power over everyone, eternal life, the elegance of his existence. When Voldemort realized he could reach Harry’s mind, it was easy for his ego to make the mistake of thinking his extraordinary talent at legilimency allowed him this unprecedented reach (probably boosted by using Harry’s blood to reanimate).

This is not the only time that Voldemort’s ego led him to make crucial errors in judgment. Snape used this to his advantage when his skill at occlumency allowed him to move within senior Death Eater circles as a spy. Voldemort never suspected that his prowess at legilimency could be bested.

Also please recall that, when Voldemort was disappointed while using the Elder Wand, he said that he did extraordinary things with it because he was extraordinary, and not because the Elder Wand had chosen him. That led Voldemort to incorrectly think that the Wand still belonged to Snape. So Snape had to die by his hand in order to have the Wand change allegiance. This mistake was a direct consequence of Voldemort’s unbridled ego.

Comment: This line in your answer - 'So Harry had to be "killed" by the only person where the Killing Curse would not work -- Voldemort.' is brilliant!! May I ask if this is your own interpretation or is there a source for it? (Just to add, even if there is no source for it, this still makes perfect sense and after reading it, the whole story is much more clearer to me now..) BTW, you seem to be an expert on 'Voldemort's ego-fuelled messes!! :-D'

Comment: @CCCC There are references to this in Rowling's books, but not captured as directly in the movies. Please give me some time and I will edit this comment with at least one book reference. To your question as to whether this is my interpretation: No, because of Rowling's books.

Comment: @CCCC Unable to edit comment above: In Book 7, Chapter 33 (page 686 in my book), Dumbledore instructs Snape that Voldemort must be the one to "kill" Harry. His quote: "And Voldemort himself must do it, Severus. That is essential". After Voldemort's Killing Curse, all of Chapter 35 is dedicated to Harry's experience in the "almost hereafter" when he talks to Dumbledore's spirit. While there he sees a pitiful, small, suffering being which represented the small part of Voldemort's soul that had attached itself to Harry -- and is now detached. Dumbledore's plan to redeem Harry's soul succeeded.